# Showing 32 bit version of a number

Tags: javascript, binary, bit

To my understanding JavaScript always converts number in binary in 32 bits right?
example

```
function dec2bin(a) {
  var b=[]
    b = a.toString(2)

  
return b
}
```

If I call `dec2bin(10)` I get 1010 but it should be

```
00000000000000000000000000001010
```

And I'm guessing it only shows the relevant bits for commodity. But what if I always want the first 16 or 8 bits?

Comment: No, all javascript numbers are 64-bit floats.

Comment: "*To my understanding JavaScript always converts number in binary in 32 bits right?*" no, the number type in JS is a 64 bit IEEE 754 float. Using bitwise operators will forcefully convert the number to a 32 bit integer for the operation but that's basically the only exception. The only other thing is BigInt which is definitely not 32 bit.

Comment: By the way `var b=[]` is rather useless, since 1. you're overwriting it immediately 2. you're not even doing anything with arrays here.

Answer (score 1):

Use **padStart** method for making a n bit string. I just modified your function by adding extra parameter noOfBits to make it dynamic and called padStart method after converting it to binary. The padStart method pads the current string with another string until the resulting string reaches the given length.

```js
function dec2bin(a, noOfBits) {
  return a.toString(2).padStart(noOfBits, '0');
}

console.log(dec2bin(10, 32));
console.log(dec2bin(10, 16));
console.log(dec2bin(10, 8));
```